# IntelliJ No Source to compile with Maven Error

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I have created a maven project in intellij and added scala framework support

This project name is **sparkexamples** and I added the necessary dependencies

Below is the project directory structure .

```
S:\surender\intellij_1\sparkexamples
S:\surender\intellij_1\sparkexamples\src\main\scala\com\test\spark\examples\DemoMain.scala
S:\surender\intellij_1\sparkexamples\pom.xml
```

I went inside S:\surender\intellij_1\sparkexamples from command prompt and started running the below mvn commands

```
 mvn clean compile
 mvn package
```

After running mvn package I could see in cons

```
S:\surender\intellij_1\sparkexamples>mvn clean compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building spark-examples 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ spark-examples ---
[INFO] Deleting S:\surender\intellij_1\sparkexamples\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ spark-exam
ples ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered  resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ spark- examples
---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.950 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-28T10:46:18+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/224M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

S:\surender\intellij_1\sparkexamples>mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building spark-examples 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ spark-exam
ples ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered  resources,
 i.e. build is platform dependent!
 [INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ spark-examples
---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources)  @ sp
ark-examples ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory S:\surender\intellij_1\sparkexamples\
 src\test\resources
 [INFO]
 [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ spark-e
xamples ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ spark- examples ---

[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ spark-examples ---
[INFO] Building jar: S:\surender\intellij_1\sparkexamples\target\spark-examples-
1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.651 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-28T10:47:09+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/225M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

S:\surender\intellij_1\sparkexamples>ole that **No Sources to compile**
```

Could Someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Post your pom.  Does it include the scala-maven-plugin? The maven-compile-plugin will not compile scala code, you need the scala plugin for that.

Comment: I closed that maven project and created a new maven project , While creating that new maven project I simply added the archetype as scala.archetype-simple and it resolved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maven compiler is "incremental" by default. (That means that just the compile goal is "incremental", Maven still makes you go through the whole [lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), by default.)

When you first did:

```
mvn clean compile
```

Your sources got compiled. (Lifecycles: you ran up to and including the `compile` lifecycle phase.)

When you then did:

```
mvn package
```

The compiler was again invoked, and observed that it had already done its work previously. (Lifecycles: `package` is a lifecycle phase extending the `compile` phase.)

This is what seems to happen. Disclaimer: you only included output for `mvn package`. If your `mvn compile` also tells you that there's nothing to compile, something else going on, and you'd probably want to rephrase your question (or post a new one).

---

Also, if this lifecycle thing is messing you up, one more hint: `compile` is a lifecycle phase, and many people confuse it with doing a particular "task", which it is not. From `mvn -h`:

```
usage: mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]
```

Again, `compile` is a *phase*, if you wanted to do a *goal* ("task"), in case of doing just compilation that'd be: `compiler:compile` (`name_of_the_plugin:name_of_the_goal`).

Comment: I have added the full compile flow console logs.. I first applied mvn clean compile and then applied mvn package. Please help